# NoMethodError at / undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, friendly-id

I have tried many solution and came up with good one but still getting error. I am editing my whole question.

I am trying to create Friendly URL with friendly_id gem.
In my project First user need to signup with devise.
Devise will pass some information to profile model with

> model/user.rb
>
> ```
> delegate :age, :city, :region, :country, to: :profile
> ```

I want to make user.name to be Friendly_id candidate. I have tried following code in my Profile model:-

```
 class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

       extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :user_name , use: :slugged 

       def user_name
       user.name
       end
```

But it is giving error

> NoMethodError at /
>   undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

now After submitting user form.

Please suggest possible solution with explanation.

My User.rb looks like

```
require 'open-uri'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 10

  validates :name , presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }

  scope :by_name, ->(name) do
    joins(:profile).where('lower(name) LIKE ?', "%#{name.downcase}%")
  end  

  delegate :age, :city, :region, :country, to: :profile

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile


      def self.new_with_session(params, session)
        session_params = { 'profile_attributes' => {} }

        provider = session['devise.provider']
        if provider && data = session["devise.#{provider}"]
          session_params['name'] = data[:name] if data[:name]
          session_params['email'] = data[:email] if data[:email]
          session_params['profile_attributes'] =
            { avatar: data[:image] } if data[:image]
        end

        params.deep_merge!(session_params)
        super.tap do |user|
          if auth = Authorization.find_from_session(session, provider)
            user.authorizations << auth
          end
        end
      end

      def password_required?
        super && registered_manually?
      end

      def registered_manually?
        encrypted_password.present?
      end

    end
```

And my profile.rb looks like

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

   extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id user.name, use: :slugged 


  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user


  validates :website, allow_blank: true, uri: true

  def website=(url_str)
    if url_str.present?
      url_str = "http://#{url_str}" unless url_str[/^https?/]
      write_attribute :website, url_str
    end
  end    

end
```

I think Problem is here:

```
Request parameters  
{"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"users/registrations"}
Please suggest possible solution and explanation.
```

And users/registration:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout 'land'

  def create
    params[:user][:profile_attributes].delete(:place)

  end  
  protected

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      welcome_path
    end
end
```

I am creating user in profile controller

```
    def load_profile
      @profile = Profile.friendly.find(params[:id])
      if !@profile || @profile.user.blocked_users.include?(current_user)
        redirect_to home_path
      else
        @user = @profile.user
      end
    end
```

@Rodrigo helped me find out error that error is due to Friendly_id can't create link with user instance.

Comment: You edited your question with other problem. The first one was resolved?

Comment: @Rodrigo I have found the cause of problem. My user model generating instance of profile. I am trying to access value of 'user' that is generated by user controller and I am trying to access its value before controller can create it. Thats why it is giving problem.

Comment: @Rodrigo I am trying to create 'user'  by 

`class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id u_name , use: :slugged 
  def self.u_name
  user = User.find(args).name
  end
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user  `

Can you tell me correct way  to write u_name method ?

Comment: the problem is I don't know what is your problem now. First, you sad that you rails server doesn't starts, and after, you edited your question with route problem. So, your server is already running without problems? when the error occurs?

Comment: @Rodrigo I never said my rails server is not starting. I was getting uninitialized constant error before and also now.

Comment: "`NameError at / uninitialized constant User::Profile` At the start of localhost:3000"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69331/discussion-between-aditya-tiwari-and-rodrigo).

Answer (score 2):

There is an error on this line:

```
friendly_id user.name, use: :slugged
```

The variable user doesn't exists at `Profile` class scope. You should use something like this:

```
friendly_id :user_name, use: :slugged 

def user_name
  user.name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extend FriendlyId
     friendly_id u_name, use: :slugged 
     def u_name
      user.name
     end 
    belongs_to :user
```

Have you defined user? what is user.name?