# Getting info from one form, saving to another model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models

1. User
2. Profile (belongs_to User)

I have 'username' in Profile model. I want to take value of 'username' in 
User new form and save it to username of Profile. How can I do that. Please suggest code.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: This is really an architectural question. Perhaps you could help us by explaining why `username` is not stored in `User`?

Comment: I agree with @Stratus3D, still if this could help you , http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @Stratus3D I want to create friendly_id url for profile view but i can't access User.username due to some calling issues thats why

Comment: I am still unsure how your models are structured. Can you paste in some of the code from the models?

Comment: @Stratus3D check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051548/nomethoderror-at-undefined-method-name-for-nilnilclass?noredirect=1#comment44525527_28051548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Add these in your Gemfile

```
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'nested_form'
```

In your user model add this

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

In your form under simple_nested_form_for

```
= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |p|
  = p.input :username
```

In you user controller
add this to permit profile parameters

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    #User Attribute Names,
    profile_attributes: [#Profile atrribute names]
  )
```

Comment: You answered exactly what i want but its giving error. Please see sample code and suggest : http://pastebin.com/9RLeQBMF

Comment: what is the error you are getting, can you show me that too.

Comment: I found the cause of error. Thanks for all your help. You really solved my problem.